# When and why was the new meta rep policy put in place?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, mso-mse-split

There must be an answer about that question, but after googling for a while, couldn't find it.

(question to be deleted if indeed it's a duplicate).

Didn't come around for a while.

Very glad the new system is in place (before: there was a separate rep for meta, now: while Q&A have their own rating, user's rep comes from SO), that reflects better the SO dedication of people answering. Was it the reason? When that happened?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "new meta rep policy" in place.

This is a side effect of [splitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014) meta.stackoverflow into a meta site for Stack Overflow and a network meta site - meta.stackexchange, for things the effect the entire Stack Exchange network.

As part of the change, meta.stackoverflow became a **normal** meta site, like the meta sites for each and every Stack Exchange site, inheriting reputation from its parent site (Stack Overflow in this case) and where upvotes/downvotes don't effect reputation on the parent site.

The Stack Exchange meta site doesn't have a parent Q&A site and is a full Q&A site with its own reputation (pretty much the way meta.stackoverflow was before it was split out).

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. While the link provided above certainly provides many details about what happened to meta/SO, people not involved in that discussion (me at least..) felt the change abruptly. Your answer fits perfectly my question - that, IMO, is not a duplicate of the link above, where the intent and content are different.